# Android admob test device not working

Tags: android, admob, libgdx

I am trying to implement admob into an app i am making. When testing the ad's on an emulator the ads show up fine, but when testing on an actual device there are no ad's.

Logcat for device:

```
02-06 17:27:56.696: I/Ads(3280): Unable to connect to network: com.google.ads.c$d: NETWORK_ERROR
02-06 17:27:56.736: D/AndroidInput(3280): sensor listener setup
02-06 17:27:56.806: D/PhoneWindow(3280): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.DefaultGLSurfaceView@4052d560 has no id.
02-06 17:27:56.816: D/AndroidInput(3280): sensor listener tear down
02-06 17:27:56.826: W/webcore(3280): hasMessages() is not supported in this case.
02-06 17:27:56.826: W/webcore(3280): hasMessages() is not supported in this case.
02-06 17:27:56.836: I/Ads(3280): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
```

Here is my java code:

```
public class HoodStarGame extends AndroidApplication {
@Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new HoodStar(), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    request.addTestDevice("7ADDEC88A42947CD1FD7F2EC2F527485");

    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14f19c2fe8d9e0"); // Put in your secret key here
    adView.loadAd(request);

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

As i said i have tried running in and emulator and that worked fine, my device is 2.3.3, which is the same as the emulator i have tested on.

Anyone know whats up?

Comment: Is your network working on your device?  (Can you browse to ads.google.com?)

Comment: Yes my network is working fine,  i connect only through wifi though, not a 3g network, could this be the problem?

Comment: The code is correct.  It's definitely a network exception; I assume you've tried requesting ads after confirming that you can reach google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Your hosts file is blocking most of the ad servers. You should probably delete it.